# Alembic file in Unity not visible on Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm doing a visualisation of an alembic file in Unity for Hololens 2 using this plugin https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/AlembicForUnity, but the file doesn't show on the headset after compiling the project. Other primitives/texts remain visible on the headset. Does anyone have a solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The HoloLens platform support for this plugin is the first thing we need to confirm.

HoloLens app is a Universal Windows Platform app and only supports IL2CPP to be the scripting back end for building projects. IL2cpp converts IL code from scripts and assemblies to C++ before creating a native binary, meantime it makes some inherent scripting restrictions, e.g. any managed code which depends upon just-in-time (JIT) compilation on the target device will fail. More information please see:[Scripting restrictions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html)

I noticed that there is an open issue has feedback that it does not support the iOS platform that also uses IL2CPP scripting back end. For now, since this repository did not clarify the list of platforms it supports, it is recommended that you open a new issue about it for professional advice.

Comment: Hi, if your problem doesn't get better, please open a support ticket by this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection, so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.